# variable in the global scope doesn't get recognized by the ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby, global-variables

I get an error for the line number 6. I try to print a global variable which the ruby interpreter doesn't recognize. why is that ? How can i modify this ?

```
localVar = "Local Variable"
$globalVar = "Global Variable"
puts(localVar)
def func
puts("From the function func")
puts(globalVar) #line 6
end

def changer
globalVar = "New Global Var"
puts("New Global Var : #{globalVar}")
end
func #Call the function func
changer #Call the function changer
```

*Output :*

```
Local Variable
From the function func
global.rb:6:in `func': undefined local variable or method `globalVar' for main:Object (NameError)
    from global.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `$` every time in front of the variable name.

```
puts($globalVar) #line 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to use the `$` prefix for global variables in Ruby, when you define or use them.

Answer (score 1):

This shall do the trick for you. $ is part of the variable name.

```
puts($globalVar)
```